# How to set a time period of 10 minutes in a MySQL

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a script run by a cronjob, it needs to send a message to the user for notification 10 minutes before the time recorded by the user (for example, the user recorded time at 14:00:00 and the message should be sent to 13:50:00)

```html
$my_base = mysqli_query($db,"
SELECT p.*
     , u.uUsername
     , u.name as userName
     , u.email as userEmail
     , u.lang 
  from my_table p
  JOIN my_table_User u 
    ON p.userId = u.userId 
 WHERE p.column_1 = 'my_table' 
   AND realized = 0 
   AND p.expiry_date = CURDATE() 
   AND p.expiry_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
)") or die("Failed to fetch data");
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Did you mean cronjob should send the notification to the user before 10 minutes of record expiry_time?
And the problem is related to cronjob though the given query is working fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow this query to find the record comes in 10 minnutes

```
SELECT username
FROM users
WHERE created_on BETWEEN NOW() + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

like in your case this should work

> SELECT p.*, u.uUsername, u.name as userName, u.email as userEmail,
>   u.lang from `my_table` p INNER JOIN `my_table_User` u ON p.userId =
>   u.userId WHERE p.column_1 = 'my_table' AND realized = 0 AND
>   p.`expiry_date` = CURDATE() AND p.`expiry_time` BETWEEN NOW() +
>   INTERVAL 0 MINUTE AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I did not specify the following, it is necessary that the script be executed only in the period from 13:50:00 to 14:00:00, the script can't be executed before and after the specified values. With your solution, the script is executed after 14:00:00. Please help, tnx!!!

Comment: this part should fulfill ur period requirement i blieve
BETWEEN NOW() + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE